# Read response from WebResponse Response Stream

Tags: http, f#, stream

I've been playing around with some basic HTTP request response operations in an F# interactive session to try and get a better feel for the language. Everything here seems to be working as expected except when I get the response stream for my HTTP request I can never seem to read anything out of it. In the following code I get the text from the printfn line every time but the value for `responseString` always seems to be empty. Am I missing anything obvious?

```
let httpListener = new HttpListener()
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8020/")

let getContext = Async.FromBeginEnd(httpListener.BeginGetContext, httpListener.EndGetContext)

let processRequest = async {
    while true do
        let! context = getContext
        let request = context.Request
        use requestReader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream)
        let requestString = requestReader.ReadToEnd()
        let response = context.Response
        use streamWriter = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream)
        streamWriter.WriteLine "A response!"
        response.Close()
}

httpListener.Start()

let maxThreads = 10
for n = 0 to maxThreads do
    Async.Start processRequest

printfn "HttpListener started with %d maximum threads processing requests." maxThreads

let sendRequest = async {
    let request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8020") :?> HttpWebRequest
    let postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Issuing HTTP")
    request.Method <- "POST"
    request.ContentType <- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength <- int64 postBytes.Length
    let requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    let! response = Async.FromBeginEnd(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse)
    let responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    use streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream)
    let responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

    printfn "Received the following response: %s" responseString
}

for n = 0 to maxThreads do
    Async.Start sendRequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to reduce the scope of usage for StreamWriter so it can be flushed on Dispose.

```
let processRequest = async {
    while true do
        let! context = getContext
        let request = context.Request
        use requestReader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream)
        let requestString = requestReader.ReadToEnd()
        let response = context.Response
        do
            use streamWriter = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream)
            streamWriter.WriteLine "A response!"
        response.Close()
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Just to be clear are you talking about the dispose that occurs when the using block is consumed? Or on response.Close()? I'm used to using blocks being scoped using {} in C# so the idea of a being able to define one on a single line is confusing to me. How come I was able to get the requestString from the InputStream without needing to scope it in the same way as you've shown?

Comment: The `use` binding is declared on one line but remains in scope until the end of the containing block, in your case the `processRequest` function or in this answer's case the `do` block. You can also use parentheses and `using` instead to reduce the scope.